# Ubuntu Phone updates are stuck at "0 byte"

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch, phone

Since two days my phone doesn’t download app updates, it’s stuck at "0 bytes":

[image: Update for two apps are at "0 byte"]

I'm at a loss because it doesn’t use `apt` and I don’t know how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you are not authenticated to UbuntuOne site. Are you able to install apps from Ubuntu store? Have you changed your UbuntuOne password lately?